# Type of wall anchors needed for TV mount

Tags: television, drywall-anchor

I had a wall-mounted television in my old house. While taking down the TV, in preparation to move it to my new house, I saw that it had utilized wall anchors. This is not a reusable wall anchor, so I need to purchase new ones to mount the TV in my new house.

I'm quite familiar with wall anchors for pointy screws and have access to hundreds of them. But these anchors for the TV look different. A non-pointy screw (for lack of a better term) with washers went into the anchor.

**Question: what is the correct term for this type of anchor? I need the term to search online so I can purchase replacement anchors.**

[image]
[image]

Comment: For something heavy or expensive/don't want to fall down, I prefer to screw into studs, maybe using plywood if mounts smaller than to hit two studs.

Comment: Those are "Toggler" toggle bolts.

Comment: `non-pointy screw` .. that is a bolt

Comment: I think you were lucky the plasterboard anchors didn't fail and drop your appliance.   Its likely a newer wall would be thinner and therefore weaker too.  Plasterboard anchors are not suitable for heavy things like TVs.

Answer (score 6):

Forget anchors. Use screws into studs. Same type of screws as for cabinets. Much stronger than anchors, toggle bolts, etc. If direct mount to studs is not an option, consider mounting plywood to studs and use that as a base for the mounting bracket.